# LEFT JOIN with id columns for all joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, json, join, left-join

I have two tables that I am applying a join to. Table A has a foreign key that references rows from Table B. SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA AS a
LEFT JOIN TableB AS b ON a.id = b.tableAId
WHERE a.ownerId = X
```

I am getting the desired result except for one thing. That is when returning the rows in JSON, only one id column is shown (TableB).

Instead I want to be able to return all id columns in the JSON where duplicate columns would have a number appended to it. For example: id, id1, id2, id3 etc...

Comment: Just give your columns more useful names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the columns that you want, explicitly giving them aliases so the names are different.  Something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.id as b_id
FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN
     TableB b 
     ON a.id = b.tableAId
WHERE a.ownerId = X;
```

Comment: is there a way to define an alias for table b.id and get all of its other columns without specifying them in the select clause ?

Comment: @Vince . . . No, there isn't, unless you use dynamic SQL.

Comment: how would I go about implementing that ? My sql is being written within a node.js API

Comment: @Vince . . . I think you should ask that as another question -- along with sample data and desired results.